# HTML <table> won't fit in container (always bigger)

Tags: html, css, styles

I have the following HTML/CSS structure:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#quad-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5%;
  right: 2.5%;
  width: 95%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.left-align {
  text-align: left;
}

.logo-img-style {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#lbl-logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="quad-main">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th class="left-align">
        <div class="logo-img-style">
          <img id="lbl-logo" src="a_img.png" />
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Problem is: Why is the table bigger than the main div ("quad-main")?
If quad-main dimensions are fixed (and they are), and and the table has 100% w and 100% h (which mean fit entirely to the parent dimensions), why in my graphic view does the table appear bigger than the div?

All table children has 100% height either, so they must not be bigger than table which, theoretically, hasn't to be bigger than the first div.

Also setting max-width and max-height will not change anything.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I think this is use full for you. You have to give the **table-layout: fixed;**
**width: 100%;** **height: 100%;** properties to **table tr** class. See below.

```
table tr {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
table tr {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#quad-main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5%; right: 2.5%;
    width: 95%; height: 20%;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.left-align {
    text-align: left;
}

.logo-img-style {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

#lbl-logo {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id = "quad-main">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class = "left-align">
                <div class = "logo-img-style">
                    <img id = "lbl-logo" src = "a_img.png"></img>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
.tabedescp {

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.table, th, td {

    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    width: 210px;
    table-layout: fixed;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Web Page Design</title>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table tbody {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#quad-main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2.5%; right: 2.5% bottom:2.5%;
    width: 95%; height: 20%;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.left-align {
    text-align: left;
}

.logo-img-style {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}

#lbl-logo {
    width: 100%; height:100px;
    object-fit: contain;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "quad-main">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class = "left-align">
                <div class = "logo-img-style">
                    <img id = "lbl-logo" src = "https://perureports.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/travel-2.jpg"></img>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The  tag is used to group the body content in an HTML table.
The  tag must be used in the following context: As a child of a  element, after any , , and  elements. useful for your coding

Answer (score 0):

The table also has `border-spacing` around the table cells and `padding` inside. Set those to 0 and the width will be as large as the width of its container.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding:0;
  border-spacing:0;    /* new */
}

#quad-main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5%;
  right: 2.5%;
  width: 95%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.left-align {
  text-align: left;
  padding:0;           /* new */
}

.logo-img-style {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#lbl-logo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="quad-main">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th class="left-align">
        <div class="logo-img-style">
          <img id="lbl-logo" src="a_img.png" />
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```